# Turn 'MsgBox' into a compile error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

We have an app that shares almost all of the code between a Winforms and a Web UI. More testing is done on the winforms version (it's used 10x more).

Programmers keep putting MsgBox into the shared code, so when testing, it appears to work. (OK, the programmer is *me*) (the platform-specific front-ends abstract another proper function to use which displays a right proper message-box style popup on both platforms).

I've disabled 'Messagebox.Show' by simply not having Winforms in the shared code. but Visual Basic happily allows the old vb6 msgbox no matter what!

So of course, IIS manages to swallow it, but, no error message on the web version.

Is there a setting I can put in the errors in visual studio to disallow this? You would think after a few of these making it into production those silly programmers (uh, I mean, I) would get the drift. Their ancient fingers have too much vb6 in them...

Comment: You could try removing the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly reference.

Comment: I suggest to invest a bit of your time to learn to use a proper logger library instead.

Comment: @steve - this is about user interaction; we have a logging library thx

Comment: @sam - I've like it if the organization would simply ... _remove Visual Basic_ entirely ;-)  Not under my control, though. All over in the program are other VB library things though, like mid (yes we know about substr...) and 20 others. Oh well...

Comment: Sorry, then I have not understood the role of these messages. I thought they were there for debug purposes and you want to remove them everywhere when you compile the code for production.

Comment: @FastAl: I've not used it, but I believe Microsoft's FxCop is capable of turning `MsgBox` into an error.  If not, and if you are using VS2015, you could write a very simple Compiler Platform (Roslyn) Code Analyzer that will generate the error (and provide a fix).

Comment: @sam - that sounds promising... I would probably have to turn off most of the stuff in FxCopy as 400K lines written without it are probably a bit 'dirty'. Disadvantage is since it's not an official tool in the company now, all who come on and off the project would have to add it - I'd like something just in the solution file.  But, we're rolling out 2015, and if I could add something to the end of the build of the top-level project that didn't require effort from newly onboarded team members, I could put it in the project myself. There are other pitfalls I could add. Something to Google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the following module to your project. It includes a `MsgBox` function that takes no arguments and returns a `Boolean`.

If you try to use `MsgBox` in your project, the compiler should pick this version rather than the VB one. Intellisense will show the "DO NOT use the VB MsgBox function" message.

If you ignore Intellisense and code `MsgBox` with any arguments, you will get a compile error as the function doesn't take any arguments.

If you code `MsgBox` with no arguments (which seems very unlikely), it will compile but will throw an exception even when run in the Windows Forms environment.

```
Module DisallowVB
    ''' <summary>DO NOT use the VB MsgBox function</summary>
    Function MsgBox() As Boolean
        Throw New NotImplementedException("MsgBox is not implemented in all cases")
    End Function
End Module
```